# The meaning of "'I wouldn't for ten pound "

Tags: meaning

> I heard through the window Father Hickey's voice, saying, '**I
>   wouldn't for ten pound that this had happened**, Phil. He's as mad as
>   a march hare. The Cardinal told me so.

This is from "Miraculous Revenge" by Bernard Shaw.
http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0606441h.html

I do not understand the meaning  below.

I wouldn't for ten pound that this had happened,

I am glad if some one would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an *idiom*, perhaps one peculiar to Ireland, or to a particular region of Ireland, and may even be obsolete given the age of the text. It appears to be a shortening of a more easily understandable saying.

Father Hickey is expressing surprise at the outburst that has just occurred and I believe he is also saying that he did not expect it.

When saying that something is unexpected, or against all odds, it is common to use gambling analogies such as "*I wouldn't bet on it*" or "*I wouldn't put money on it*". It is also very common in regional dialects for words to be shortened, contracted, or even omitted from common phrases.

The meaning of the expression in your text may then actually be:

> I wouldn't **have bet** for ten pound that this **would have** happened.

In 1885 when the book was written, ten pounds would have been a considerable sum of money. [The inflation calculator](https://www.moneysorter.co.uk/calculator_inflation2.html) suggests it would be equivalent of £898.41 today. So this expression is also an example of hyperbole.

Answer (score 1):

You can also understand the phrase as, "I wouldn't want this to happen, not even if someone paid me ten pound (to permit it happen)".